# Reading list of integers into an Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, io

I am working on a program in C++ that will read integers from a file, then pass them to a function that checks for a Subset Sum.

The file is formatted like so:

```
number of cases n

sum for case 1
list of integers separated by a space

sum for case
list of integers separated by a space

sum for case n
list of integers separated by a space
```

My problem now lies in how to read the list of integers into an array to be passed to my function.

This is my main so far:

```
    fstream infile("subset.txt");

    if(infile.is_open()){

    int numCases, num;

    infile >> numCases;

    while(infile >> num){
        for(int i = 0; i < numCases; i++)
        {
            int sum;
            int set[30];

            num >> sum;
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if(num == '\n')
                {
                    sum[i] = -1
                }
                else 
                {    
                    num << sum[i]
                }
            }

               int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);

                if(subsetSum(set, n, sum) == true)
                    printf("True");
                else
                    printf("False");
        }
    }
}

else
    printf("File did not open correctly.");

return 0;
```

Any help you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, this is for an assignment, so if you would rather just give me hints that would be appreciated as well. The assignment is for the algorithm and I have that working, I just need a hand with the I/O.

Comment: num == '\n' won't work because you are reading an int, not a character.  Maybe use getline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read the line containing the list of numbers using `std::getline`, then use an `istringstream` to parse numbers out of that string.

I'd also use a `std::vector` instead of an array to hold the numbers. For the actual parsing, I'd probably use a pair of `std::istream_iterator`s, so the code would look something like this:

```
while (infile >> sum) {
    std::getline(infile, line);
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    std::vector<int> numbers{std::istream_iterator<int>(buffer), 
                             std::istream_iterator<int>()};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << subsetSum(numbers, sum);
}
```